# ¿Como hacer un peer search?

Tags: javascript, ip, nodos, busqueda, blockchain

Estoy creando una blockchain y debe ser decentralizada como una red peer to peer. Cuando me conecto tengo que sincronizar con otros nodos. Cuando hago pruebas se de antemano que ips tienen los demas ya que los creo yo mismo, pero para producciÓn necesito un sistema que encuentre algunas ip que esten live para conectarme. Vamos, el tipico problema "peer Search". Habia pensado en una api que se conectan todos y de ahi podemos bajar la lista de peers online pero esta solucion no es satisfactoria ya que depende de esta api centralizada para obtener las ip de los nodos centralizando esta parte de la blockchain y por ello no tiene sentido. La idea es que se pueda obtener algunas IP de otros nodos para sincronizarse de forma decentralizada. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que utilices el método de Bitcoin/IPFS, que es teniendo bootstraps nodes. Los bootstraps nodes (BN) son **nodos confiables** que proveen la información inicial para que los nuevos nodos puedan entrar a la red, dado que quieres hacer una red decentralizada siempre es bueno que puedas crear una clase de protocolo para validar los nodos que están entrando a la red, y los que salen (por timeout por ejemplo), banear nodos poco confiables, etc. Recuerda que una red decentralizada ocasiona la desconfianza de los nodos entre si, por eso es que se crean estos nodos confiables.
Este es un ejemplo de [Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/bootnodes.go). (Estos son llamados boot nodes)

El que tengas un conjunto de BN no signifique que tu red sea centralizada, al contrario, ayudan a la red que los nodos nuevos se conecten a los nodos confiables. Si vas a hacer que tu lista de nodos bootstrap sea dinamica, toma en consideración que un ataque puede llegar a ser fatal. La idea es que los BN no tengan privilegios o ventajas sobre otros nodos, simplemente sirvan para proveer la información inicial.

Un consejo a nivel técnico es que utilices un protocolo distinto a HTTP (como grpc) para una comunicación más rápida.